# Vue compile ao inserir no DOM

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Eu preciso inserir um elemento compilado no `DOM`, porém ele será inserido em um lugares aleatórios, não em um lugar pré definido como está documentação...

```
var res = Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>')
new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})
```

Todas as abordagens com `v-for`, `v-if/show` não me servirão pois também necessitam de elementos pré-definidos.

tentei algo assim...

```
document.getElementById('elPai').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>'));
```

Ele retorna um objeto contendo `render` e `staticRenderFns`, porém não achei o resultado compilado nesses objetos, **me parece** que ele está gravado em uma `promisse`, que é desencadeada quando o elemento é pré-definido no DOM.

Por fim, há como inserir elementos compilados no DOM com `vue 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver

Primeiro de tudo, **creio eu** que componentes adicionados dinamicamente não conseguem se comunicar aos métodos internos da instância vue mas sim com seus próprios métodos, por fim, para adicionar um componente ao DOM usei `$mount`...

```js
let comp = Vue.component('comp', {
  template: '<div @click.stop="alert">Hello!</div>',
  methods : {
   alert () {
     alert('hello');
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  methods : {
    replace () {
     new comp().$mount('#test');
    }
  },
  components : {
   comp
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="app" @click.stop="replace">
  
    <div id="test">
    test
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Referência [Andrejs Abrickis Medium](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)